# How to get the status value from a status function in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the status of a product in jQuery. I have this function to get the status of my product:

```
getStatus: function () {
  var status = 'Active';
  if (this.get("Terminated") === '1') 
    status = 'Terminated';
  else if (this.get("PR_Active") != '1') 
    status = 'Inactive';
  return status;
},
```

I thought about doing something like this to show it in the DOM:

```
$('#status').append(getStatus()); //obviously this is not working :(
```

in a span like this:

```
<span id="status"></span>
```

However I'm not seeing the result. How do I use the `getStatus()` function to display the actual status of my product?

Comment: Appending the return value from `getStatus()` should work fine. It looks like the issue is simply how you access the function. It looks like it's a property of an object, so presumably it should be something like: `$('#status').append(yourObject.getStatus())`

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan answer. If still does not work please post some for code so we can identify the issue. the code you have provided is not enough.

Comment: If you aren't using class structure you can define function using **equal(=)** and not **colon(:)**. Thus `getStatus: function () {............ }` would be written as `getStatus =  function () {................}`, provided get() function is already defined.

Comment: Allright! yes, I agree with both of you. Im trying to access the function as @RoryMcCrossan suggested, if it does not work I will pick up some relevan code to try to identify better this issue :) thanks both!

Comment: Working now! it was exactley what you where saying, I was accesing the function in a wrong way. Thanks a lot @RoryMcCrossan. I'll post my solution so it can be usefull for others!!! Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and it was exactley what you where saying. I was accesing the function in a wrong way... now it looks like this:

```
$('#status').append(this.getStatus(status));
```

And VOILA!